# Where does Keras store downloaded data for MNIST?

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I ran the script below:

https://github.com/antoniosehk/keras-tensorflow-windows-installation/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py

I believe these lines downloaded the data.

```
from keras.datasets import mnist    
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

I am running this script on Windows 10. Where ist the data being stored? I would like to clean up because my disk space is limited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can always check the Keras code on github. In your case you need the **get_file** function here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/e77a4cf3f85b45ad4275dfd661073ace1cc06e5a/keras/utils/data_utils.py#L123

And the answer to your question is:

> By default the file at the url `origin` is downloaded to the
> cache_dir `~/.keras`, placed in the cache_subdir `datasets`,
> and given the filename `fname`. The final location of a file
> `example.txt` would therefore be `~/.keras/datasets/example.txt`.

Answer (score 9):

I will answer my own question.

I found it here. I am using Windows 10.

```
C:\Users\<user_name>\.keras\datasets
```

Comment: in WinPython, I found it in: C:\WPy-3662\settings\.keras\datasets

Answer (score 0):

I just couldn't find anywhere in the locations mentioned above (`C:\Users\<user_name>\.keras\datasets`). But, ensured that the dataset is stored locally because it works even after I turned my internet (WiFi) Off. Hunt is still on. I also searched for `mnist.npz` in my local hard drive but could not find it.

Comment: you can specify path while loading the dataset mnist.load_data(path="YOUR_PATH_TO_A_FILE") for example "c:\dataset.txt"