# Tensorflow Keras Dataset Filepath within PyCharm

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pycharm, mnist

I have seen [this question and the answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51807254/where-does-keras-store-downloaded-data-for-mnist/51807316) This doesn't help. I have **MAC** environment. Used **Anaconda**. And there is **no .Keras folder under users directory.**

I was following a tutorial. To load the built-in **MNIST** dataset I used the following codes:

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

# Load MNIST data 
(x_train, y_train), (x_test,y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

I am using Anaconda to install the packages and Pycharm for coding. Imported the environment in PyCharm. After showing download messages in console, it's loading the images directly from second time.

[image]

Nonetheless, I want to see the downloaded MNIST images/data to get a complete understanding. I mean I want to see if it's a zip / raw images / text data etc. I don't see a newly created folder. Does anyone where the dataset was saved by Keras within PyCharm project?

Comment: I found that: You can customize where the data is saved/loaded by specifying data_dir= ( defaults to ~/tensorflow_datasets/

Comment: @ThomaS Keras Dataset Load_data function doesn't have a attribute named data_dir
https://keras.io/datasets/

Comment: "~/tensorflow_datasets/" This worked. Found under users. Provide as answer. @ThomaS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the data should be saved in ~/tensorflow_datasets/

Comment: under users directory.

Answer (score 0):

On windows it's found in
C:\Users\Yourname\keras\datasets

Answer (score 0):

on mac, it's usually `<user_directory>/.keras/datasets/`