# saving a list of images into the disk in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow

when I run the following like of code

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

the image data in x_train takes away a lot of space in ram
I want to store data of x_train in a folder in disk so that I'd retrieve those images batchwise while training

and then I want to load the whole/half of the  list from the disk to ram
what would be the easiest way to reach there ?

Comment: I think Keras saves the dataset to disk as a temp file. check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51807254/where-does-keras-store-downloaded-data-for-mnist.
As for loading and batching. You can use keras `flow_from_directory`

Comment: ok, makes sense
But what I still want to do is process these images, store them in the disk and then use them

Comment: batching is only a way to not getting OOM issues in this case. Your image processing should be the same, the only difference is that now you have at every `time stamp`  a portion of your data